# Android multiple fragments architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to write an app that contain three separate but similar flows. When the user launches the app he will be able to choose what he wants to do(within the 3 flows). For each of them, there will be an instruction screen, a progress visualisation screen and a capture screen(using the camera), plus other specific screens.

I want to be able to reuse parts of the code so as to not write 3 times the same/similar thing. However, I'm not sure of the architecture.
My idea is to have one activity per flow with multiple fragments for the different screens. In this case would it be a good idea to create a `BaseActivity` that extends `Activity` and implements the listeners to deal with the fragment switching? The each of my fragments would also extend a `BaseFragment` that takes care of the common code.

Is my logic correct? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Your logic makes sense. But how will you present your 3 `BaseActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. Personally I do not like `BaseActivity`, no doubt it provides common code but sometimes it becomes very difficult to manage `BaseActivity`.

Another good approach, is to use interface for communication and sharing data (between fragments and activities)